# Does Atomic operation need synchronization in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

As far as I understand atomic operation are one that are indivisible that is one thread can see the state of a system before thread 2 changes it or after the change made by thread 2 but not in between.

say for example I have a method on a shared object betwwen 2 threads:

```
public void incrementMe() { 
 //incrementing a shared int for this example
 atomicInt.incrementAndGet();
}
```

that for example that the initial value of our atomic int is 5. Now thread 1 and thread 2 are both calling incrementMe at the same time. what will happen? as far as I understand thread 1 will see the value 5 and increment it to 6 at the same time thread 2 will see the value 5 since the increment is atomic so thread 2 can see the value after change of after but no in between so it increment it to 6 and at the end I will have the value 6 instead of 7. Am I right? Do I miss somthing?

Thank u in advance

Comment: Nothing in the `java.util.concurrent` package requires synchronization; that's the entire point of the classes.

Comment: This should help too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691983/implementation-of-the-addandget-in-atomicinteger-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is incorrect.  Atomics by definition are completed in a single operation.  Behind the scenes the JVM is using the `Unsafe.compareAndSwap` method, which models a single processor instruction that will increase a value without the fear of pre-emption.  So, Thread 1 will increment the value to 6 and Thread 2 will increment the value to 7.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But I still not understand, after all no side effects of an atomic operation is visible until the action/operation is complete.So if 2 threads try to in increment shared value simultaneously not thread can see the effect of the other...

Comment: Not true.  I think you do not trust or understand what we are saying.  When using atomics only one thread at a time can modify the value.  Think of it like this, when a thread goes to read or write an atomic then all context switching is disabled.  That's not what really happens, but it's a decent model.

Comment: @disrvptor Can you provide any references to information regargin JVM using Unsafe.compareAndSwap? I need to understand how pre-emption will be avoided.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995856/strange-behavior-in-sun-misc-unsafe-compareandswap-measurement-via-jmh is a good writeup of how to examine what's going on. Examples of the CAS function can be found at https://www.baeldung.com/java-unsafe and https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.java

Answer (score 2):

It is completely adjusted for precisely that use case. If two threads read one will come before the other. One will receive 6, the other 7. Neither will see the value 5.

Remeber to keep the incremented value, though.

```
 public void incrementMe() {
   int xx = atomicInt.incrementAndGet();
 }
```