# Strange behavior in sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwap measurement via JMH

Tags: java, cas, microbenchmark, jmh

I've decided to measure incrementation with different locking strategies and using JMH for this purpose.
I'm using JMH for checking throughput and average time as well as simple custom test for checking correctness.
There are six strategies:

- Atomic count
- ReadWrite locking count
- Synchronizing with volatile
- Synchronizing block without volatile
- sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwap
- sun.misc.Unsafe.getAndAdd
- Unsynchronizing count

Benchmark code:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode({Mode.Throughput, Mode.AverageTime})
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@Fork(1)
@Warmup(iterations = 5)
@Measurement(iterations = 5)
public class UnsafeCounter_Benchmark {
    public Counter unsync, syncNoV, syncV, lock, atomic, unsafe, unsafeGA;

    @Setup(Level.Iteration)
    public void prepare() {
        unsync = new UnsyncCounter();
        syncNoV = new SyncNoVolatileCounter();
        syncV = new SyncVolatileCounter();
        lock = new LockCounter();
        atomic = new AtomicCounter();
        unsafe = new UnsafeCASCounter();
        unsafeGA = new UnsafeGACounter();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void unsyncCount() {
        unsyncCounter();
    }

    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public void unsyncCounter() {
        unsync.increment();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void syncNoVCount() {
        syncNoVCounter();
    }

    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public void syncNoVCounter() {
        syncNoV.increment();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void syncVCount() {
        syncVCounter();
    }

    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public void syncVCounter() {
        syncV.increment();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void lockCount() {
        lockCounter();
    }

    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public void lockCounter() {
        lock.increment();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void atomicCount() {
        atomicCounter();
    }

    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public void atomicCounter() {
        atomic.increment();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void unsafeCount() {
        unsafeCounter();
    }

    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public void unsafeCounter() {
        unsafe.increment();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void unsafeGACount() {
        unsafeGACounter();
    }

    @CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
    public void unsafeGACounter() {
        unsafeGA.increment();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options baseOpts = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.class.getSimpleName())
                .threads(100)
                .jvmArgs("-ea")
                .build();

        new Runner(baseOpts).run();
    }
}
```

And results of bench:

**JDK 8u20**

```
Benchmark                                         Mode  Samples   Score    Error   Units
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.atomicCount      thrpt        5  42.178 ± 17.643  ops/us
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.lockCount        thrpt        5  24.044 ±  2.264  ops/us
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.syncNoVCount     thrpt        5  22.849 ±  1.344  ops/us
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.syncVCount       thrpt        5  20.235 ±  2.027  ops/us
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.unsafeCount      thrpt        5  12.460 ±  1.326  ops/us
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.unsafeGACount    thrpt        5  39.106 ±  2.966  ops/us
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.unsyncCount      thrpt        5  93.076 ±  9.674  ops/us
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.atomicCount       avgt        5   2.604 ±  0.133   us/op
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.lockCount         avgt        5   4.161 ±  0.546   us/op
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.syncNoVCount      avgt        5   4.440 ±  0.523   us/op
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.syncVCount        avgt        5   5.073 ±  0.439   us/op
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.unsafeCount       avgt        5   9.088 ±  5.964   us/op
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.unsafeGACount     avgt        5   2.611 ±  0.164   us/op
o.k.u.u.UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.unsyncCount       avgt        5   1.047 ±  0.050   us/op
```

The most of measurement as I expect, except `UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.unsafeCount` which is used `sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwapLong` with `while` loop. It the the slowest locking.

```
public void increment() {
    long before = counter;
    while (!unsafe.compareAndSwapLong(this, offset, before, before + 1L)) {
        before = counter;
    }
}
```

I suggest that low performance is because of while loop and JMH makes higher contention, but when I've checked correctness by `Executors` I get figures as I expect:

```
Counter result: UnsyncCounter 97538676
Time passed in ms:259
Counter result: AtomicCounter 100000000
Time passed in ms:1805
Counter result: LockCounter 100000000
Time passed in ms:3904
Counter result: SyncNoVolatileCounter 100000000
Time passed in ms:14227
Counter result: SyncVolatileCounter 100000000
Time passed in ms:19224
Counter result: UnsafeCASCounter 100000000
Time passed in ms:8077
Counter result: UnsafeGACounter 100000000
Time passed in ms:2549
```

Correctness test code:

```
public class UnsafeCounter_Test {
    static class CounterClient implements Runnable {
        private Counter c;
        private int num;

        public CounterClient(Counter c, int num) {
            this.c = c;
            this.num = num;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                c.increment();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void makeTest(Counter counter) throws InterruptedException {
        int NUM_OF_THREADS = 1000;
        int NUM_OF_INCREMENTS = 100000;
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_OF_THREADS);
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_THREADS; i++) {
            service.submit(new CounterClient(counter, NUM_OF_INCREMENTS));
        }
        service.shutdown();
        service.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Counter result: " + counter.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + counter.getCounter());
        System.out.println("Time passed in ms:" + (after - before));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        makeTest(new UnsyncCounter());
        makeTest(new AtomicCounter());
        makeTest(new LockCounter());
        makeTest(new SyncNoVolatileCounter());
        makeTest(new SyncVolatileCounter());
        makeTest(new UnsafeCASCounter());
        makeTest(new UnsafeGACounter());
    }
}
```

I know that it is very awful test, but in this case Unsafe CAS two times faster than Sync variants and everything goes as expected.
Could somebody clarify described behavior?
For more information please see GitHub repo: [Bench](https://github.com/kirmit/algorithms_and_utils_benches/blob/develop/utils%20bench/src/main/java/org/kirmit/utils/unsafe/UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.java), [Unsafe CAS counter](https://github.com/kirmit/algorithms_and_utils_benches/blob/develop/utils%20bench/src/main/java/org/kirmit/utils/unsafe/concurrency/UnsafeCASCounter.java)

Comment: Maybe I'm reading the table wrong but 20 operations per microsecond looks faster than 12 operations per microsecond. Wouldn't that make the sync variants faster than UnsafeCAS? Also the 5.9 us/op error on UnsafeCount looks pretty wide compared to the rest of the results that could be throwing things off.

Comment: Theoretically the sync variants should be the slowest as shown in my custom test(to check correctness). But in JMH version UnsafeCAS is the slowest. It looks fishily and I can only suggest why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thinking out loud: it is remarkable how often people do 90% of the tedious work, and leave the 10% (where the fun begins) for someone else! All right, I'm taking all the fun!

Let me repeat the experiment first on my i7-4790K, 8u40 EA:

```
Benchmark                                 Mode  Samples    Score    Error   Units
UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.atomicCount      thrpt        5   47.669 ± 18.440  ops/us
UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.lockCount        thrpt        5   14.497 ±  7.815  ops/us
UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.syncNoVCount     thrpt        5   11.618 ±  2.130  ops/us
UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.syncVCount       thrpt        5   11.337 ±  4.532  ops/us
UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.unsafeCount      thrpt        5    7.452 ±  1.042  ops/us
UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.unsafeGACount    thrpt        5   43.332 ±  3.435  ops/us
UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.unsyncCount      thrpt        5  102.773 ± 11.943  ops/us
```

Truly, something seems fishy about `unsafeCount` test. Really, you have to presume all data is fishy before you validated it. For nanobenchmarks, you have to validate the generated code to see if you actually measure something you want to measure. In JMH, it is **very quickly doable** with `-prof perfasm`. In fact, if you look at the hottest region of `unsafeCount` there, you will notice a few funny things:

```
  0.12%    0.04%    0x00007fb45518e7d1: mov    0x10(%r10),%rax    
 17.03%   23.44%    0x00007fb45518e7d5: test   %eax,0x17318825(%rip)
  0.21%    0.07%    0x00007fb45518e7db: mov    0x18(%r10),%r11    ; getfield offset
 30.33%   10.77%    0x00007fb45518e7df: mov    %rax,%r8
  0.00%             0x00007fb45518e7e2: add    $0x1,%r8           
  0.01%             0x00007fb45518e7e6: cmp    0xc(%r10),%r12d    ; typecheck 
                    0x00007fb45518e7ea: je     0x00007fb45518e80b ; bail to v-call
  0.83%    0.48%    0x00007fb45518e7ec: lock cmpxchg %r8,(%r10,%r11,1)
 33.27%   25.52%    0x00007fb45518e7f2: sete   %r8b
  0.12%    0.01%    0x00007fb45518e7f6: movzbl %r8b,%r8d          
  0.03%    0.04%    0x00007fb45518e7fa: test   %r8d,%r8d
                    0x00007fb45518e7fd: je     0x00007fb45518e7d1 ; back branch
```

Translation: a) `offset` field gets re-read on each iteration -- because CAS memory effects imply volatile read, and therefore the field needs to be pessimistically re-read; b) the hilarious part is that `unsafe` field is *also* being re-read for a typecheck -- for the same reason.

This is why high-performance code should look like this:

```
--- a/utils bench/src/main/java/org/kirmit/utils/unsafe/concurrency/UnsafeCASCounter.java       
+++ b/utils bench/src/main/java/org/kirmit/utils/unsafe/concurrency/UnsafeCASCounter.java       
@@ -5,13 +5,13 @@ import sun.misc.Unsafe;

 public class UnsafeCASCounter implements Counter {
     private volatile long counter = 0;
-    private final Unsafe unsafe = UnsafeHelper.unsafe;
-    private long offset;
-    {
+    private static final Unsafe unsafe = UnsafeHelper.unsafe;
+    private static final long offset;
+    static {
         try {
             offset = unsafe.objectFieldOffset(UnsafeCASCounter.class.getDeclaredField("counter"));
         } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
-            e.printStackTrace();
+            throw new IllegalStateException("Whoops!");
         }
     }
```

If you do that, the `unsafeCount` performance boosts right up:

```
Benchmark                              Mode  Samples   Score    Error   Units
UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.unsafeCount    thrpt        5  9.733 ± 0.673  ops/us
```

...which is fairly close to synchronized tests now, given the error bounds. If you look at the `-prof perfasm` now, this is an `unsafeCount` loop:

```
  0.08%    0.02%    0x00007f7575191900: mov    0x10(%r10),%rax       
 28.09%   28.64%    0x00007f7575191904: test   %eax,0x161286f6(%rip) 
  0.23%    0.08%    0x00007f757519190a: mov    %rax,%r11
                    0x00007f757519190d: add    $0x1,%r11
                    0x00007f7575191911: lock cmpxchg %r11,0x10(%r10)
 47.27%   23.48%    0x00007f7575191917: sete   %r8b
  0.10%             0x00007f757519191b: movzbl %r8b,%r8d        
  0.02%             0x00007f757519191f: test   %r8d,%r8d
                    0x00007f7575191922: je     0x00007f7575191900
```

This loop is very tight, and it seems nothing can make it go faster. We spend most of the time loading the "updated" value and actually CAS-ing it. But we contend a lot! To figure out if contention is the leading cause, let's add backoffs:

```
--- a/utils bench/src/main/java/org/kirmit/utils/unsafe/concurrency/UnsafeCASCounter.java       
+++ b/utils bench/src/main/java/org/kirmit/utils/unsafe/concurrency/UnsafeCASCounter.java       
@@ -20,6 +21,7 @@ public class UnsafeCASCounter implements Counter {
         long before = counter;
         while (!unsafe.compareAndSwapLong(this, offset, before, before + 1L)) {
             before = counter;
+            Blackhole.consumeCPU(1000);
         }
     }
```

...running:

```
Benchmark                                 Mode  Samples    Score    Error   Units
UnsafeCounter_Benchmark.unsafeCount      thrpt        5   99.869 ± 107.933  ops/us
```

Voila. We do *more* work in the loop, but it saves us from contending a lot. I tried to explain this before in ["Nanotrusting the Nanotime"](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/), it might be good to go back there and read up more on benchmarking methodology, especially when heavy-weight operations are measured. This highlights the pitfall in the entire experiment, not only with `unsafeCount`.

Exercise for the OP and interested readers: explain why `unsafeGACount` and `atomicCount` perform much faster than other tests. You have the tools now.

P.S. Running N threads on machine having C (C < N) threads is silly: you might think you have "contention" with N threads, but instead you are running and "contending" C threads only. It is especially amusing when people do 1000 threads on 4 core machine...

P.P.S. Time check: 10 minutes to do the profiling and additional experiments, 20 minutes to write it up. And how much time you wasted replicating the result by hand? ;)

Comment: Hm, what would be a good consumeCPU(1000) alternative without JMH API. In your Nanotrusting article you had exerimented with smaller token numbers. I guess there are two things to it, having a realistic frequency/contention and having a backoff. Would a Thread.yield() be enough with realistic contention? I guess using a busy method is better for the CPU caches?

Comment: Thread.yield() alone is not a good alternative -- its impact is largely unpredictable, to the extent it can be ignored completely. You need the consumeCPU-style backoffs for cases like these. Doug Lea et al. have even more complicated busy-loops in heavily-contended places in j.u.c.* code.