# Java concurrency issue - map with AtomicInteger counter

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, atomic

I have several threads working at the same time to increment a counter in a map. For some reason the below doesn't work with the counter sometimes not incrementing (in the below Indices is an enum class):

```
public class TheoreticalWorkload{

    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<Indices, AtomicInteger> WORKLOAD = new ConcurrentHashMap<Indices, AtomicInteger>();

    public void update(Indices id, Integer change){
        int i = WORKLOAD.get(id).addAndGet(change);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought declaring the counter as an AtomicInteger would prevent several threads accessing it at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Please post something that does.

Comment: When its not updating, are you sure its not because the update function isn't being called?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas yes I'm sure as it is actually printing the same number twice

Comment: Having it print the same number twice doesn't mean the update function is being called correctly.  You could have two different buckets be added to consecutively and the produce the same number printed out twice.

Comment: Can you change your print to: System.out.println(id + " " + i); ? This way you can see if the duplicate number is for the same index.

Comment: @DavidtenHove thanks David, I tried that and still getting the issue.

Comment: We don't know how the map is populated (as is, it would generate NPEs every time). We also don't know how Indices is implemented: it could be mutable, have an incorrect equals() or hashCode(). Post all the needed code. Another possibility is that TheoreticalWorkload is loaded by two class loaders.

Comment: An `AtomicInteger` ensures operations are atomic without locking (see the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17691983/3080094)), it does not prevent several threads accessing it at the same time (that would defeat the whole point of these classes in the concurrent package).

Comment: Everyone thanks for bearing with me - you put me on the right direction by questioning my update function. Turns out the integer in the stripped down version above updated correctly, but I had a concurrency problem in my displaying of the integer in a GUI. I tested it by adding some sleep() statement before updating my display and it worked fine, will now think of a way to sort out my display. Looks like something like SwingUtilities.invokeLater might do the trick.